# Blackberry HTTP Connection

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me, httpconnection

```
    public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    public MyScreen()
    {
        MyScreen myScreen = new MyScreen();
        String a = myScreen.getPage("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println("+++  "+a);
    }
    public void parse(String xml){

    }
    public String getPage(String url) {
        String response = "";

        try {
            StreamConnection s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);

            InputStream input = s.openInputStream();

            byte[] data = new byte[256];
            int len = 0;
            StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();

            while( -1 != (len = input.read(data))) {
                raw.append(new String(data, 0, len));
            }

            response = raw.toString();

            input.close();
            s.close();
        } catch(Exception e) { }

        return response;
    }
}
```

This is the code I want to execute to get Http Contents in Blackberry. I got exception of StackOverflow. Please give me help with example.

Comment: StackOverflow will try to solve StackOverflow exception :)

Comment: Where did the exception occur?

Comment: I am new on blackberry. I don't know where exactly the exception occurs. But My friend when ever i execute my application I got the message on my emulator.

Comment: Instead of having one try - catch, add many, one around each line or call. One for raw.append, one for close, one for toString etc, etc until you find the line which gives you the exception. Usually you will find the problem then.

Comment: The Array of Byte is not enough to store data fetched from Google.com - Is there any other way store contents from any website dynamically?

Comment: My friend! Can you please send me working code to fetch contents of any website. dynamically. Please store contents in ArrayList or Vector of Strings.

Answer (score 3):

Just try searching on StackOverflow - there are a lot of info on this.

**UPDATE**:

Basically BB networking consists of 2 points:

1. Detecting what network transport to use. This is BB spesific. Have you heard about network transports? If not, then check [Connecting your BlackBerry - http and socket connections to the world](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/m-p/206243). Basically you end up with a url that is appended with a spesific string that tells to the BB internals what network transport to use.
2. Using `HttpConnection` for the got url at step 1 to retrieve data from network. See the API docs on [HttpConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html). There are sample code in there.

Comment: This rather be a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a BlackBerry developer guide - [Code sample: Creating a connection over HTTP by using the first available transport](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/CS_create_first_available_HTTP_connection_857706_11.jsp) - that will surely help you.

Comment: This would be a great comment ;)